# Can one meditate in the "anechoic" chamber?

Tags: meditation

It is not necessarily but I wonder what would happen if monk will meditate in  **"anechoic" chamber**?

**The Orfield Labs room was recognized as the quietest in the world**

[image]

If you stand in it for long enough, you start to hear your heartbeat.
A ringing in your ears becomes deafening. When you move, your bones make a grinding noise.
Eventually you lose your balance, because the absolute lack of reverberation sabotages your spatial awareness.

[Here is link](https://edition.cnn.com/style/article/anechoic-chamber-worlds-quietest-room/index.html)

> **There will be -20db silence in the room.
>
>   So may we know how much db of silence (internally) is produced while mediating?**

**So will monk be able to meditate in this room or he will suffer the effect of it?**

**When we can hear heartbeat, bones grinding noise will he able to concentrate on breathing and could meditate without suffering?**

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that skandhas are different in that chamber, compared to life outside of it?

Comment: Wouldn't be different and when enters in jhana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it really matters. When I meditate, sometimes I hear a car passing or a bird singing or a child laughing in the distance; sometimes I hear a scrap of music in my head, dredged up from some distant memory; sometimes I hear the sound of my breathing, or my heart beating, or the creak of a joint as my body settles. These are just sounds, of no particular importance. They come and they go. For someone unpracticed in meditation that kind of silence would be disorienting, because the outer silence exposes all of their inner noise. But meditation reaches for inner quietness.

Comment: **But meditation reaches for inner quietness.** that's why I thought it is possible to meditate. There will be -20 db silence so may we need to know how much db silence is produced while meditation.

Comment: @Swapnil: inner quietness is a mental state, not a question of volume that's measure in decibels. it's a state in which we aren't reactive to disturbances of the mind, whether that means intrusive external noises or intrusive mental conditions brought on by the lack of external noise.

Comment: @@Ted Wrigley Thank you so much. Now I've got.

Answer (score 3):

Yes in a video ajahn brahm said that ajahn chah went into such a room. I think he said there was nothing special according to ajahn Chah.
The video was some Q&A, but you can ask for more on his forum https://bswa.org/forum/

Comment: I'll ask Ajahn Brahm personally if ti is done by Ajahn Chah. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I  never been  to anechoic chamber but I think that place is  favorable  for such deep meditation  because  when we meditate we become more aware of ourselves  some use body scan techniques  while meditating in that kind of meditation  if we are about  to hear our heartbeat  and blood flow  it'll  be easy to become  more aware of ourselves
usually  while meditating  we focus  our breath and if mind wanders we again  shift focus  to breath  and also we listen  to voices around  us become  more aware so in my opinion  I think it'll  be easy to  become aware in anechoic  chamber  this kind of chamber reminds me of Buddha caves in ajantha in india